# How to convert a list to an ordered list in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a method to convert a list to an ordered list in javascript.

My list is :

```
list = new List<Car> { new Car{ Name = "BMW" }, new Car{ Name = "Ford" }, new Car{ Name = "Lamborghini" }, new Car{ Name = "Fiat" }, new Car{ Name = "Alfa" } }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: with `array.map` and `array.join`

Comment: I think im asking the wrong question

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
cars.map((car)=>car.Name).join(', ')
```

First, you want to extract the name of every car, then join them by commas.